# Modify css class with Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I'm currently writing a little chrome extension to modify an existing site. I try to modify one div element if the child contains an attribute with the value (for example red, blue, ...). If the child contains a value with the attribute value red I want the parent div colored in red and so on.

I've worte this JS:

```
//find the parent div element
element = element.getElementsByClassName("existing-class-to-find-div")[0];
// check if the attribute from the child is blue
...
if (color == blue){
   element.className += " RedColorClass";
}
```

if I printout the elmenent with element.outerHTML or the className everything is fine and I see the new value. BUT on the actual site there is still the old value and it isn't changed. Do I have to trigger something to refresh the html site or so?

Comment: Changes made in _JavaScript_ are dynamic for that instance and do not become hard code

Comment: just out of curiosity : what happens if you do : `if (color == "blue")` ?

Comment: Use devtools to inspect the element and check the applied CSS. Maybe there is another rule that affects the element and it has more specificity.

Comment: If inspect the element I can see the div tag with all classes and there isn't the new class, only the old ones. BTW. I didn't use that color == blue example in my code, it's just a little example to show you what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Could you post the relevant css.

Comment: I've added a new CSS tag RedColorClass with background color red. If I add the RedColorClass into the div tag manually (with the chrome debugging tool) the color is changed to red. So I don't think the css file is the problem. The problem is, the class isn't added to the div element.

Answer (score 0):

Use `element.classList.add("RedColorClass")` or, if you use jQuery:

```
 $(element).addClass("RedColorClass");
```

Comment: Yes, that's a better way, but `element.className += " RedColorClass"` should also work. So the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer. Still the same problem. I used element.classList.add("RedColorClass"). I've added                     console.log("new classes: " + element.className); after the command and see that the new class wass added to the list but it still not modifies the actual site :(

Comment: @tk What are the values of `color` and `blue` variables?

Comment: sry, this condition isn't really part of my real code. I just want to give a generic example to illustrate the problem. The condition works fine and only applies if the child attribute contains the color red.

Comment: Nope, no error(s). I've put "console.log("HTML: " + element.outerHTML);
" after I've added the new class and got this output: HTML: <div class="existing-class-to-find-div RedColorClass"  ... > ... So I think the java code should be correct?!

Comment: @tk Yep. The class is added. Please add your `RedColorClass` CSS code.

Comment: I think I've found the problem. It works, but not for every item. I've always looked at the end of all elements and there are onl some modified elements on the top of the document. I think there is another problem. Sry..

Answer (score 0):

If doing this without a lib, the style sheet object might be a better target to modify.

The this I am assuming is changing the background to red for the class .existing-class-to-find-div, based on comments. It is best to move that info into the question.

The style sheet itself is a different object.

```
var CSSStyleSheet = document.styleSheets[0]; /*danger this is first style sheet not necessarily the correct sheet */
CSSStyleSheet.addRule(".existing-class-to-find-div", "background-color:red");
```

The source code of the style sheet will not be changed, but the devtools should show the change.

On the code which is pasted vars color and blue are not defined. I suspect that is where the problem is.